# relações do mysql no laravel 5.5

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5

Estou tentando modelar com Laravel um banco de dados pra compras, no meu mysql as relações [estão assim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBu6b.png), então fui modelar no Laravel, para a tabela associativa "fornecedor_detalhe_item" eu usei relação "belongstoMany", deu certo usando o tinker.

Agora vem o problema:

1. junto com os detalhes(fornecedor_detalhe) e os items eu gostaria de conseguir ter acesso as outras tabelas relacionadas com "fornecedor_detalhe" que são "fornecedor" e "formapagto".
2. E também gostaria de linkar essa tabela associativa "fornecedor_detalhe_item" numa relação n:m com outra tabela pra ter mais uma tabela associativa "fornecedor_detalhe_item_rci".

Eu criei um modelo pra "fornecedor_detalhe_item", mas não sei exatamente como fazer isso.

Não cheguei a codificar nada, apenas estou tentando modelar a mesma coisa no laravel.

Se tiverem alguma sugestão sobre o MER aceito também.

Obrigada

Comment: Acho que é o caso de você criar o model da "tabela pivot".

Comment: utilizando o modelo da pivot eu posso definir relação "belongsToMany" com outra tabela? ai eu escrevo essa relação no pivot e na outra tabela? e pra se referir a mais modelos eu tenho que usar o "has-many-through"?